# AS2 How to make array buttons (MC) that can modify the value of a global array variable?

Tags: arrays, variables, click, actionscript-2, movieclip

In the first frame of the movie, I declared an array variable and create movieclips:

```
frame = new Array();
for(i=1; i<=5; i++){
    frame[i] = "empty";
    var a = attachMovie("box", "box"+i, i, {_x:i*100, _y:100});
}
```

I want to use the variable frame[] to count how many times the movieclips are clicked.
I came to make a class for the movieclip "box" which I use, but couldn't figure out how to find out which button is clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not even need to create a class for box, just pass index i as parameter to each movieclip in method attachMovie:

```
frame = new Array();
for(i=1; i<=5; i++){
    frame[i] = "empty";
    var a = attachMovie("box", "box"+i, i, {_x:i*100, _y:100, index:i});
    a.onMouseDown = function ()
    {
        trace(this["index"])
    }
}
```

After that each box knows its own index in frame array.

Comment: oh, perfect and quick answer, thanks a lot!
O_o , didn't know I can do a.onMouseDown = function(){...}
thanks again!